# How to send nested query parameters using python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, mitmproxy

I'm struggling to do a proper `POST` using python `requests`. I'm analysing a site using `mitmproxy` and the params being sent are listed as

```
_cmc.workload: {
 "Requests": [
   {
     "Service": "CourseOfSalesGet1",
     "TId": 11,
     "Request": {
       "Page": 1,
       "Stock": "BHP"
     },
     "DeferExecution": false,
     "SkipCache": false
   },
   {
     "Service": "QuoteGet1",
     "TId": 12,
     "Request": {
       "Stock": "BHP"
     },
     "DeferExecution": false,
     "SkipCache": false
   }
 ]
}
```

I converted that to :

```
params={
'_cmc.workload': {"Requests":[{"Service":"CourseOfSalesGet1","TId":"11","Request":{"Page":"1","Stock":"BHP"},"DeferExecution":"false","SkipCache":"false"},{"Service":"QuoteGet1","TId":"12","Request":{"Stock":"BHP"},"DeferExecution":"false","SkipCache":"false"}]}
}
```

Headers from mitmproxy:

`content-type:  application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
x-requested-with:   XMLHttpRequest
accept-language:    en-au
accept-encoding:    br, gzip, deflate`

I converted the headers to this:

```
headers={
'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'accept':'application/json, text/javascript, */*',
'x-requested-with':'XMLHttpRequest',
'accept-language':'en-au',
'accept-encoding':'br, gzip, deflate'
}
```

and my `POST` was of the form

```py
requests.session.post('https://www.example.com', headers=headers,data=params)
```

I'm using a session since login is required for the site and I've handled that fine. Just can't figure out how to send the post data correctly as the response from the site says I sent an empty request.

The post works fine though when replayed on `mitmproxy`. How can I get this to be sent properly?

Comment: You've listed params for the POST. But you haven't mentioned how exactly are they sent with `mitmproxy` (`Content-Type` of the request).

Comment: Can you add all request headers to the question?

Comment: @IvanVinogradov I've updated to include headers

Answer (score 0):

Ok got this working by simply adding quotes to the inner dictionary as shown:

```
params={
'_cmc.workload': '{"Requests":[{"Service":"CourseOfSalesGet1","TId":"11","Request":{"Page":"1","Stock":"BHP"},"DeferExecution":"false","SkipCache":"false"},{"Service":"QuoteGet1","TId":"12","Request":{"Stock":"BHP"},"DeferExecution":"false","SkipCache":"false"}]}'
}
```